# Does this mathematical result have a specific name?

Tags: number-theory

I am not sure if it's new although it may be an easy consequence of some theorem or lemma.The result is as follows:
By choosing a set of numbers between $0$ and $n$(for any $n$) picking each number at most once and summing them you can create any number between 0 and $n(n+1) / 2$ .
The above result can be easily proven by induction.

Comment: This is a roundabout way of defining triangular numbers. $T_n = 1+2+3+...+n =  n(n+1)/2$ which is typically proved inductively. Add up a subset of $\lbrace 1...n\rbrace$, you get a smaller number.

Comment: I do not think there is a special name for this but it is a special case of the [subset sum problem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SubsetSumProblem.html): the subset sum set of an initial segment of natural numbers is another initial segment of natural numbers.